# How to use pivot_longer as a newbie

Tags: r, tidyr

I have this datasett that looks like this:

```
|Data   |World|1   |2   |3   |
|Country|Code |1960|1962|1963|
|Norway |NOR  |3.5 |2.7 |5.4 |
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
|Norway |Year |
|3.5    |1960 |
|2.7    |1962 |
|5.4    |1963 |
```

I really struggle with understanding how `pivot_longer` works, can someone explain it to me and help to make the datasett correct.

Comment: I don't think you need to pivot this data, but transpose it. `t(df)` might get you close. Perhaps a larger and more realistic section of your data would get a more accurate answer though.

Comment: Please share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Also, what did you try so far?

Comment: @deschen honestly I don't understand ```pivot_longer``` so I have just tried putting random values like ```values_to="Data"```etc, to see if it works.

Comment: `pivot_longer` explained - https://r4ds.hadley.nz/data-tidy.html#how-does-pivoting-work

Answer (score 1):

Considering your dataset has the years as column names, like this:

```
country   world_cd    1960  1962   1963
Norway    NOR          3.5   2.7   5.4
Canada    CAN          3     2.9    5
```

Then you can use the `pivot_longer()` function like this:

```
pivot_longer(cols = the columns that will pivot. In the example I chose setup an index by excluding country and world_cd that will be fixed using ! ,
names_to = new variable col name to hold the pivoted column names, except those in the parameter cols above (e.g. 1960, 1962, 1963),
values_to= new variable col name to hold the pivoted values , except those in the parameter cols above (e.g. 3.5, 2.7, 5.4)
```

E.g.

```
pivot_longer(cols = !c(country, world_cd), names_to= 'year', values_to= 'vals')
```

The result will be:

```
country world_cd   year   vals
<chr>   <chr>     <chr>   <dbl>
1 Norway  NOR      1960    3.5
2 Norway  NOR      1962    2.7
3 Norway  NOR      1963    5.4
4 Canada  CAN      1960    3  
5 Canada  CAN      1962    2.9
6 Canada  CAN      1963    5
```

See that `country` and `world_cd` keep fixed as indexes and the other columns not specified in the parameter `col` will pivot.
The name of those pivoted columns will go under a new variable `names_to` and the values under a new variable `values_to`

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer! It made me understand ```pivot_longer```better!